# how to preg_match url with http and without it

Tags: php, url-shortener

I am working on a shorting script, and ran into a problem when it comes to http:// being passed along with the URL.

**Problem:** If the user does not provide a link with http:// in it the script can't process it and returns invalid url error, not something that should happen as preg_match should parse http, https and links without either one of them.

Here is the code snippt responsible for checking for http

```
$url = $_REQUEST['url'];  

  if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+$/i", $url)) {  
    $html = "<h1 id='upc' style='padding:8px 8px;text-align:center;'>Error: invalid URL</h1>";  
  } else {  
    $url = $_REQUEST['url'];
```

What would be the best way to fix it and allow for parsing of http & https and parsing of links without either http or https

Comment: What exactly defines a valid URL in your specific case?

Comment: @PeeHaa the URLs are passed from index file to process file. The process file uses the first bit of code if(!preg_match.... to see its structure which is the problem here. The URL is self is passed via $url = $_REQUEST['url'] value which should be $_POST but I never revised the code until now

Comment: In terms of the user NOT submitting `http://` or `https://` always assume `http://`

Comment: You could look into [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) might save you some hassle. Particularly example #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    // $url is valid
} else {
    // $url is NOT valid
}
```

It doesn't check to see if the protocol is valid (so `foo://www.foo.com/bar` validates but `foo:/\www.foo.com/bar` does not), but it's a start.  Per the docs, [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) isn't meant to validate URLs.